# Create new column by concatenating two columns with fillna with existing column values in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Need to create a new column with using existing three column (city,state,country), have to =
fill null value of city column with 'None' + replace null values of state column with country column value.

```
NEW COLUMN "CITY_STATE"
         
OUTPUT - 
           city          state        country          CITY_STATE
           A             MH           INDIA            A MH
           NULL          NULL         POLAND           NONE POLAND
           NULL          AZ           RUSSIA           NONE AZ
           E             NULL         SOUTH AFRICA     E SOUTH AFRICA
         

 raw_data = raw_data.withColumn('city_state',F.concat(col('city').fillna('None'),lit(' '),col('state').fillna(col('country'))))
```

This is showing **'TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable** error

How can I achieve my desired output? Do I need to break it into couple of steps or this can be done in a single command?

Comment: Provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and sample data. for the col('state'), instead of  fillna try when otherwise and see if it works.

Comment: @HArdRese7 this data would help to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it in a single command is like below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, concat_ws

row = Row('city', 'state', 'country')
row_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [row('A', 'MH', 'INDIA'), row(None, None, 'POLAND'), row(None, 'AZ', 'RUSSIA'), row('E', None, 'SOUTH AFRICA')])
row_df.show()

row_df = row_df.select('city', 'state', 'country',
                       concat_ws(' ', when(row_df.city.isNull(), "NONE").otherwise(row_df.city),
                                 when(row_df.state.isNull(), row_df.country).otherwise(row_df.state)).alias(
                           'CITY_STATE'))
row_df.show()
```

The output will be like below:

```
+----+-----+------------+
|city|state|     country|
+----+-----+------------+
|   A|   MH|       INDIA|
|null| null|      POLAND|
|null|   AZ|      RUSSIA|
|   E| null|SOUTH AFRICA|
+----+-----+------------+

+----+-----+------------+--------------+
|city|state|     country|    CITY_STATE|
+----+-----+------------+--------------+
|   A|   MH|       INDIA|          A MH|
|null| null|      POLAND|   NONE POLAND|
|null|   AZ|      RUSSIA|       NONE AZ|
|   E| null|SOUTH AFRICA|E SOUTH AFRICA|
+----+-----+------------+--------------+
```

To know more about spark-SQL read [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html).